# HP Envy 32 No sound

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I have been trying to troubleshoot my audio issue by myself for the past couple of days and came up with no success. I have an HP Evy 32 AIO dualboot (fastboot disabled) with an ALC 274 sound card. Speakers and headphones don't work but bluetooth does.  I have tried the troubleshooting steps for different distros which were Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora, Manjaro, and Pop_os.  I am new to Linux so bare with me.

Links to the things I have tried:
https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=276789
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=363010
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=329074
https://github.com/thesofproject/sof

I'm not really sure if I installed the sof firmware correctly but I used the rsync with symbolic link method because I couldnt get the script to work.

Heres my alsa-info link: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=166ea703a7d63bd8206a3925f67b6b18cefacc01

Here is Inxi:

```
unkel_ted@ubu:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-32-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: HP product: HP ENVY All-in-One 32-a0xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 86C6 v: 0010 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.25 date: 04/10/2023
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: Intel Core i7-9700 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Coffee Lake
    rev: D cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 2 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2175 high: 3000 min/max: 800/4700 cores: 1: 3000
    2: 3000 3: 3000 4: 3000 5: 800 6: 3000 7: 800 8: 800 bogomips: 48000
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU104M [GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER Mobile / Max-Q]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nvidia v: 535.86.05 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Quanta HP 5M Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-5:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 6144x3456~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-32-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 3b:00.0
  IF: enp59s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtw_8822ce v: N/A port: 3000
    bus-ID: 3c:00.0
  IF: wlp60s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-7:3
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0
    bus-ID: 00:17.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.4 TiB used: 26.21 GiB (1.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: HBRPEKNX0202AH size: 476.94 GiB
    temp: 34.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Intel model: HBRPEKNX0202AHO size: 27.25 GiB
    temp: 46.9 C
  ID-3: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 860 EVO 1TB size: 931.51 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.32 GiB used: 26.18 GiB (2.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 34.9 MiB (36.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 1.5 MiB (0.1%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 54.0 C pch: 57.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 287 Uptime: 45m Memory: 15.41 GiB used: 3.71 GiB (24.1%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Packages: 1834 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Dmesg:

```
unkel_ted@ubu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[    2.022332] ata3.00: Features: Trust Dev-Sleep NCQ-sndrcv
[    4.257634] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.257681] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)
[    4.973649] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.825457] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC274: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.825461] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.825462] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.825464] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.825464] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.825465] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    5.825466] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
```

Pacmd Not Running:

```
unkel_ted@ubu:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB,   front-right: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC274 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC274 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6043110000 irq 173"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

Pacmd Running:

```
unkel_ted@ubu:~$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB,   front-right: 30129 /  46% / -20.25 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 75.57 ms
    max request: 14 KiB
    max rewind: 14 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 75.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 1837.50 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC274 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC274 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6043110000 irq 173"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a348"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

Aplay

```
unkel_ted@ubu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC274 Analog [ALC274 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

-The only thing I havent really messed with is hdajackretask but I have ran RtHDDump.exe to compare and everything looked fine.

-The only success I have had was running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-fix.conf <<<'options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=3'
```

which gave me my sof driver

-Running a windows vm and installing the realtek drivers in vm.  That did give me sound.

-Also I dont know if this is any help but I have an option in bluetooth for "HP Envy Speaker". When I connect to it all it does is try to use the speaker as a microphone.

-I should also throw out that I have Nvidia Optimus.  I did disable it tho and try some stuff with no success.

-If you would like anything else feel free to ask.  I am currently at a fresh install of Ubuntu just in case anyone wants to go back to the basics.